# Bad idea to force creation of Mercurial remote heads (ie. branches)?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I am developing a centralized web application, and I have a centralized Mercurial repository.

Locally I created a branch in my repository

```
hg branch my_branch
```

I then made some changes and committed. Then when I try to push, I get

```
abort: push creates new remote branch 'my_branch'!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)
```

I've just been using push -f. Is this bad? I WANT multiple branches in my central, remote repository, as I want to 1) back up my work and 2) allow other developers to develop with me on that branch.

Is it bad or something to have branches in my remote repository or something? Should I not be doing push -f (and if not, what should I do?)? Why does Joel say this in his tutorial:

[image]
<sub>(source: [grabby.info](http://grabby.info/3c0370f58efd4da29ad651cec9c14750.png))</sub>

Occasionally I've made a change in a branch, pushed, switched to another branch, and changes I had made in that branch I switch to were mysteriously reverted to a previous version from several commits ago. Maybe this is a symptom of forcing a push?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099432/branching-with-mercurial-scm

Comment: creating new remote *named* branches is fine, having multiple heads for a given named branch is bad though (it's what Joel warns about). I think recent hg doesn't require -f anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suspicion is that others with more time can answer better, but here is something related I found:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Prevent_a_push_that_would_create_multiple_heads

It is related to a different option (specifically breaking push -f), but it mentions something along the lines of what you ask:

> While a plain 'hg push' will warn you if you're going to create new heads, that is merely a warning on the client side intended to help/remind users that they may have forgotten to merge first.

Assuming this is an accurate statement then you are perfectly safe to do so.

Note however that I have only basic knowledge in Mercurial so shouldn't be used as a source of complete truth :).

Comment: Since it says in the documentation what you quoted, it seems pretty definitive to me that it's okay to use push -f and have remote branches.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not bad to force the push when you create a new branch. The error/warning is issued because the new branch causes the repository to have two *topological* heads. That is, there are now two changesets without children: the tip of your default branch, and the tip of your new branch.

With Mercurial 1.6 (to be released in two weeks time) you will be able to do

```
hg push --new-branch
```

to allow the creation of new remote branches. This is safer since `--force` disables all safety guards, whereas `--new-branch` only allows you to create a new branch.